# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ move $x_0$ and $\alpha^t(x_0)=\beta^t(x_0)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{Z}$, prove that $\alpha=\beta$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two $r$-cycles in $S_n$ for which exist a $x_0$ $\in$ {$1, 2, ..., n$} such that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ move $x_0$ and $\alpha^t(x_0)=\beta^t(x_0)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{Z}$, prove that $\alpha=\beta$

(Help: I don't know how to start the proof)

Comment: Let $\alpha=(x_0\ x_1\ x_2\ \dots\ x_{r-1})$. Compute $\alpha^t(x_0)$. Then you know what $\beta^t(x_0)$ is. Use that to write out $\beta$ as a cycle.

Comment: Did that help??

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: yes it helped, thanks

Comment: If you can solve the problem, let me encourage you to write up your solution and post it here as an answer.